# Deploying webpack and react express app to Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, webpack

I'm trying to deploy a Webpack, React, Express app to Heroku, but it is not working. Here's the scripts object from my `package.json`

```
    "scripts": {
      "dev": "node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
      "test": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint src && mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive ./test",
      "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
      "start": "cd server && node index.js",
      "postinstall": "webpack -p"
    },
```

For local development, the express server runs on `localhost:8081` and the react app runs on `localhost:8080`

To enable the action creators to actually communicate with the Express API, I set up the API calls as below (just an example):

`` const request = axios.get(`http://localhost:8081/api/forecast?latitude=${latitude}&longitude=${longitude}`); ``

Could I get some advice/suggestion on how to better structure this?

Comment: wait, shouldn't you include your webpack config file in your postinstall? `"webpack -p --config ./webpack.prod.config.js --progress"`

Comment: I'll give that a shot. How do I send the api request from the action creators to the api? Currently, its hardcoded to localhost:8081

Comment: Is there any reason `/api/forecast?latitude=${latitude}&longitude=${longitude}` is not working? You shouldn't hardcode localhost into your requests..

Comment: Well, locally they are running on different ports right. when i do `npm run dev` it starts on localhost:8080 and `npm start` it starts express on 8081. If I try on the same port, it doesn't work and it says `Cannot GET /`

Comment: Hey @SeanKwon, I got this working. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hey @TarangHirani I have a similar problem. Could you post your solution? Thanks!

Comment: Yup. Here's my package.json https://github.com/tarang9211/darksky-react-redux/blob/master/package.json
I needed to add some dev dependencies to my dependencies.